# 3D points projection to 2D XY plane

Tags: c++, math, 3d, geometry, projection

I have a 3 Dimentional point set (x,y,z).I need to project these points into 2 dimentional XY plane using orthogonal projection. so my question is, how to convert these points into 2D? is it correct if I make Z=0 only? If it is not correct please any one help me to slove this problem. Also I want to programming this in C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the axes of your coordinate system are orthogonal to each other, you get the orthogonal projection to the xy-plane by simply setting the z coordinate to zero -- you are right with this.

Comment: i don't have any new scale factor,shift between two system. simply need to project 3D points into xy plane that's mean same origin,scale.is it ok if i used http:/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection?